# How to set initialState using Redux Toolkit with data using Apollo's useQuery?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, graphql, redux-toolkit, apollo-client

I am trying to call the useQuery hook (something not allowed outside of functional components), in a redux toolkit slice. Is this something that is doable, perhaps using createAsyncThunk or some similar method? My application is built with the MERN stack, so my database is MongoDB, and I'm using Graphql to fetch the data. (I'm ignoring the reducers in this example because I'm just focused on getting the data in and setting it to the initial state.)

```
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { GET_USER_SETTINGS } from "../graphql/queries/settingsQueries";

const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_USER_SETTINGS);

const { gridView } = data.settings;

const initialState = {
   gridView,
};

const settingsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "settings",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setGridViewOff(state) {
      state.gridView = false;
    },
    setGridViewOn(state) {
      state.gridView = true;
    }, 
},
});

export const { setGridViewOff, setGridViewOn } = settingsSlice.actions;

export default settingsSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that you cannot call `useQuery` from the Redux slice code. What I'd suggest here is to use some "undefined" initial `gridView` state and use the `useEffect` hook to "initialize" the `gridView` value.

Something similar to the following example:

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
   gridView: undefined,
};

const settingsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "settings",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    initializeGridView: (state, action) => {
      state.gridView = action.payload;
    },
    setGridViewOff(state) {
      state.gridView = false;
    },
    setGridViewOn(state) {
      state.gridView = true;
    }, 
  },
});

export const {
  initializeGridView,
  setGridViewOff,
  setGridViewOn
} = settingsSlice.actions;

export default settingsSlice.reducer;
```

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { initializeGridView } from "../path/to/settings.slice";
import { GET_USER_SETTINGS } from "../graphql/queries/settingsQueries";

const useInitializeGridView = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { loading, data } = useQuery(GET_USER_SETTINGS);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading) {
      const gridView = !!data?.settings?.gridView;
      dispatch(initializeGridView(gridView));
    }
  }, [loading, data]);
};
```

Call `useInitializeGridView` somewhere in your app near the root where Redux is in scope, e.g. under the Redux `Provider` component in the ReactTree. Any UI that is dependent on the `state.settings.gridView` value should check first if it is defined, *then* use the defined true/false value.

Answer (score -1):

You can handle this by creating a Redux Thunk action to fetch data and set the initial state and then dispatch the Redux Thunk action from your component.

**Example**

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import { GET_USER_SETTINGS } from "../graphql/queries/settingsQueries";

export const fetchUserSettings = createAsyncThunk("settings/fetchUserSettings", async (_, { dispatch }) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await useQuery(GET_USER_SETTINGS);
    const gridView = data.settings.gridView;

    return { gridView };
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
});

const initialState = {
  gridView: null,
};

const settingsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "settings",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setGridViewOff(state) {
      state.gridView = false;
    },
    setGridViewOn(state) {
      state.gridView = true;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(fetchUserSettings.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.gridView = action.payload.gridView;
    });
  },
});

export const { setGridViewOff, setGridViewOn } = settingsSlice.actions;

export default settingsSlice.reducer;
```